# JQuery $.get with .NET/ASPX

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When developing in `PHP` the `JQuery` `$.get` is very useful when using *real-time* functions to register and login.

The issue I have is that when I load a clean/blank .aspx file/form, default code rests on the index which is read in the response in `JQuery` so I'm finding to hard to find the data I wanted to send as the response.

Is there an easier way than displaying the response as:

`:Response1:Response2:Response3:` etc...

and then starting the JavaScript `.split(":");` at the point `[1]` index?

Because if there are `:` before the response, e.g. in a pre-created function (default) it seems to split them and I never know when the start of the response is.

Its becoming a pain to work with because you don't know when the response ends either, is there a way to use `JQuery` `$.get` in `.NET` which can receive a response?

Don't see what difference this makes @Mason but here you go:

```
var email = document.getElementByID("email");
// etc..
$.get( "login.aspx", { email: email, password: pass } )
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

in an `$("#btn").click` function...

But the whole thing I am saying is `data` holds the whole index page, I want it to only hold my response.

Comment: Your server can respond to HTTP requests with whatever resposne you want. I don't know how you're getting `:Response1:Response2:Response3:` but it would probably be helpful if you included the server side code generating your response, and also included an example of your jQuery `$.get` call.

Comment: the `.done(data)` function in JQuery reads everything off the index page, but in ASP.NET there is a default index page so if I wanted to send back: 'Error: False credentials' I would just output it to the page and the JQuery `data` would hold that. But because there are default things in the index page the `data` holds all that default stuff aswell so I cannot find what I send out.

Comment: Like I said, *show your code* in your question.

Comment: Like I just explained, what difference will that make? @mason It would be the same for everyone....

Comment: No, it's not. We can't make assumptions about what your code is doing. You need to provide the relevant code so that we can understand what you are doing and explain why it's wrong.

Comment: I `think` what you are looking for is `JSON` a great way to represent data in a string and share with REST

Comment: I added my code, like its gonna make any difference lol..... the aspx automatically makes a default index page to you can use the backend .aspx.cs file... so the index will always have some default code on... I am asking if there is a way to determine where my response starts and finishes....

Comment: It makes a huge difference, because now I understand what you're doing. You are new to this site, and I've been on this site for years. If you don't believe that adding code to your question is helpful, you'll just have to trust someone who's got a lot of experience.

Comment: But the code has nothing to do with the question, the `.done` function in JQuery pulls the index of the page you sent the request to which ASPX makes a large default sort of coding to so my response is in the middle of the default code it makes... I am asking how I can find my response in JQuery. My method was wrapping it in random characters and then splitting the `data` so I can see where my response is but the issue with that is I cannot see what `index` it starts/finishes at @mason (thats the basics of how the `.done` function works for everyone, not just certain code)

Comment: I am telling you here and now that seeing the code was helpful because it shed some light on what you were trying to do so I could see what the issue is. Any arguing about that is really a waste of time.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6b18d930c04abf2057fdb38af918bcf5 => https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is solved by not responding via a Web Forms page. Web Forms pages are meant to render HTML to the end user, they are not meant for sending arbitrary bits of data to a client. You need to use a more appropriate tool for the job.

One tool is called an HTTP Handler. A request can be routed to a handler, which can write whatever data it wants to the client. The data could be plain text, JSON, XML, a binary file, anything you want.

A certain kind of handler is called a Generic Handler, and it's very simple to get started with because it's similar to Web Forms. It involves creating an ASHX file (and if you're using the code behind technique, an ASHX.CS file).

Let's do a generic handler. Create an ASHX file and put this content in it:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Now when you make an HTTP request to the URL that maps to your ASHX file, you'll get the text "Hello World". Now you can change it to return whatever data to your page that you wish.

There are other alternatives. You could use MVC or [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api), but this should be enough to get you started and handle a very simple use case.